# Is there any Ubuntu twitter app that handles scheduled tweets?

Tags: software-recommendation, twitter, social

I'm looking for an app that can schedule tweets for future times, rather than only tweeting now, as Gwibber does. I'm looking for a native Ubuntu app because:

1. I'd prefer using something that's free software and
2. Web-apps such as Hootsuite have a limit to how many profiles you can manage before having to pay for their service.

Thanks in advance.

Edited to add: I would like a twitter app that does the above *and* has a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

There are some command line Twitter clients, like `twidge` or `bti` that you can use with [at](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/at.1.html) or [cron](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/cron.8.html) the schedule tweets.

Comment: Thanks for the accurate answer. I should have specified I'm looking for something with a GUI.